# GNU ld removes section

Tags: linker, embedded, arm, ld, gnu-assembler

I'm writing a boot script for an ARM-Cortex M3 based device. If I compile the assembler boot script and the C application code and then combine the object files and transfer them to my device everything works.

However, if I use `ar` to create an archive (libboot.a) and combine that archive with the C application there is a problem:

I've put the boot code in a section:

```
    .section    .boot, "ax"
    .global     _start

_start:
    .word       0x10000800  /* Initial stack pointer (FIXME!) */
    .word       start
    .word       nmi_handler
    .word       hard_fault_handler
    ... etc ...
```

I've found that `ld` strips this from the final binary (the section "boot" is not available). This is quite natural as there is no dependency on it that `ld` knows about, but it causes the device to not boot correctly.

So my question is: what is the best way to force this code to be included?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding something like:

```
KEEP(*(.boot))
```

in the `ld` linker script to tell the linker to keep the `.boot` section.

However, I'm not sure if this is enough to cause `ld` to pull in any objects from the archive that are in the `.boot` section - it might not consider an object at all unless some symbol in that object is causing it to be pulled in. If this is a problem, specifying `_start` as the entry point (using `-e _start` on the ld command line or using `ENTRY(_start)` in the linker script) may be the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to pass the **--no-gc-sections** option to the linker.  From the [GNU ld documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/index.html):

```
--gc-sections
--no-gc-sections

Enable garbage collection of unused input sections.

`--gc-sections' decides which input sections are used
by examining symbols and relocations. The section
containing the entry symbol and all sections containing symbols
undefined on the command-line will be kept, as will sections
containing symbols referenced by dynamic objects.
Note that when building shared libraries, the linker must
assume that any visible symbol is referenced. Once this initial
set of sections has been determined, the linker recursively marks
as used any section referenced by their relocations.
See `--entry' and `--undefined'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The linker will only extract from an archive those objects required to resolve explicitly referenced symbols.  Your start-up code is not explicitly referenced because it is invoked via the reset vector.

If your boot code comprises multiple modules you should create a *partially linked* object file using ld and the [-r / --relocatable](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002d_002drelocatable-88) option, this will combine the objects into a single object without the need to resolve all symbols (such as main() for example).  This can then be used in a full link with your application code.  If it is only a single object file then there is no real advantage in creating an archive in any case (and as you have found it won't work).

Note that traditionally GNU C runtime start-up is provided in a file called crt0.o (not an archive) presumably for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `--whole-archive` when linking but it's a big elephant gun.  The man page claims:

> For each archive mentioned on the command line  after  the  `--whole-archive`  option,  include  every object  file  in  the archive in the link, rather than searching the archive for the required object files.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ld --whole-archive option to pull in unreferenced symbols. This  [ld options page](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/ld/Options.html) has this for whole-archive
--whole-archive

> For each archive mentioned on the
>   command line after the --whole-archive
>   option, include every object file in
>   the archive in the link, rather than
>   searching the archive for the required
>   object files. This is normally used to
>   turn an archive file into a shared
>   library, forcing every object to be
>   included in the resulting shared
>   library. This option may be used more
>   than once.
>       Two notes when using this option from gcc: First, gcc doesn't know
>   about this option, so you have to use
>   -Wl,-whole-archive. Second, don't forget to use -Wl,-no-whole-archive
>   after your list of archives, because
>   gcc will add its own list of archives
>   to your link and you may not want this
>   flag to affect those as well.

Also see this question on stack overflow, [uses of whole-archive option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805555/ld-linker-question-the-whole-archive-option)