# Linux makefile does not linking with lib

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

have following code in makefile

```
LIB_FILES = $(CURL_LIB) $(CRYPT_LIB) 

$(ROCK_SHARED_LIB):$(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
@echo "Linking shared object ... $(BINDIR)/$@"
gcc -shared $(SRC_FILES:.c=.o) $(OBJ_FILES) $(LIB_FILES) -o $(BINDIR)/librock.so
```

And in output I see:

```
gcc -ldl -Wl,-R'$ORIGIN' -Wl,--undefined, -shared /usr/local/rocker/lib/libcurl.a /usr/local/rocker/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -o /home/build/13.0/su/librock/linux/librock.so
```

What means that gcc saw libcrypto file which should be linked to, but for some reason it did not link it to my file. File size output is the same as without libcrypto and I get unresolved externals from it.

Why is it so ? Cause according to output it looks like everything went ok but for some reason lib file was not linked at all ?

Thanks on advance.

Comment: How do you see that "it looks like everything went ok" if you don't get any output? What undefined symbols are reported?

Comment: Maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459829/object-file-from-a-not-included-in-so

Comment: `pkg-config --cflags --libs libcrypto` will provide you with the proper compiler and linker arguments.

Comment: When/where/what are the "unresolved externals" you are getting?

Comment: I got unresolved externals when I run program which loads so file.

Comment: Are you sure that that line of output corresponds to that piece of code? Where are those flags (`-ldl -Wl,-R'$ORIGIN' -Wl,--undefined,`) coming from? Are `SRC_FILES` and `OBJ_FILES` really empty? Are you actually trying to build a shared object library out of static libraries? Are you sure you know how to do that? What happens if you try a simpler example by hand, without Make?