# Static lib loading related issue

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, static-libraries

Suppose I want to version the libs in binaries made. For static libs, I thought this approach would work but it does not:

> ***LibInfo.h*** - Base class for all libinfo classes. Registers an object in `gvLibInfo` vector when a child is constructed.

```
#ifndef IFACE_H
#define IFACE_H

#include <vector>

class LibInfo;
extern std::vector<LibInfo*> gvLibInfo;

class LibInfo
{
    public:
        virtual int getversion() = 0;
        void reglib()
        {
            gvLibInfo.push_back(this);
        }

        LibInfo()
        {
            reglib();
        }
        virtual ~LibInfo()
        {}
};


#endif
```

> ***Lib1.h*** - Derived from LibInfo and creates an object `l1`. Lib2.h is the same except `getversion` returns 2.

```
#ifndef LIB1_H
#define LIB1_H

#include "LibInfo.h"

class Lib1 : public LibInfo
{
    public:
        int getversion()
        {
            return 1;
        }

    private:
};

Lib1 l1;

#endif
```

> ***main.cpp***

```
#include "Lib1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<LibInfo*> gvLibInfo;

int main()
{       
    for(vector<LibInfo*>::iterator it = gvLibInfo.begin(); it != gvLibInfo.end(); it++)
    {       
        cout << (*it)->getversion() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling -

```
g++ -c Lib1.h -o Lib1.o
g++ -c Lib2.h -o Lib2.o
ar cr lib.a Lib1.o Lib2.o
g++ main.cpp -o app -L/home/duminda/statictest/lib.a
```

When I run, nothing happens. I thought this maybe due to one of several reasons:

1. At the time `Lib1 l1` is made, `gvLibInfo` has not been constructed.
2. I saw somewhere that the linker will remove any unused variables from a static lib. However, when I run on the binary `nm` it shows up this :

0000000000603280 B gvLibInfo

0000000000603270 B l1

0000000000603278 B l2

I guess `l1` & `l2`(The corresponding object of class `Lib2` are there but what does that 'B' flag mean?
3. Something else I don't know.

Comment: I ran a gdb session. It does indeed seems that the vector gets constructed after static lib is loaded. Then,
1. Can I delay the lib load or force vector to be constructed earlier somehow?
2. Or, do I just have to use primitive data types?

Comment: Further, if I remove `#include "Lib1.h"` from main.cpp and replace it with `#include "LibInfo.h"` then I `nm` does not show the symbols `l1` and `l2`.

Comment: :D. My first problem is solved. `__attribute__((init_priority()))` took care of that. Now I want someone to help me with the problem above. :)

Comment: This is the question where you should update with the --whole-archive thing.

Comment: But, if I did, no one will notice would they?

Comment: You can comment under the answers, just to say you updated your question. the people who already answered will notice. And I think updating your questions pops it up, but I am not sure. You can also do the opposite, and replace your dummy Test classes in the other questions with your more meaningful libinfo. People can come up with alternative design, or find the question more interesting. They first reaction won't be : why would you do that in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805555/ld-linker-question-the-whole-archive-option) propose to use the --whole-archive flag.
The main difference is, instead of referring to an external object, the library refers
to an external function.

Linking does not occur with -L, but with -l, i.e. it should be :

```
-L/path/to/libdir -lname
```

If your library is :

```
/path/to/libdir/libname.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the top of main.cpp to look like this, so that the vector is created before the derived instances.

```
#include "LibInfo.h"

std::vector<LibInfo*> gvLibInfo;

#include "Lib1.h"
#include "Lib2.h"
```

BTW, the 'B' from nm indicates symbol in BSS (uninitialized data).  The man page for nm has all the symbol types listed.