# init_priority attribute on variables in static libs

Tags: c++, linux, g++

This is a new question after my long rant. The problem here is, I have a global `vector<Base*> vObjs` in my main application and I got `Derived obj`s in each **static lib** linked to the application. If I specify the `vObjs` to have an init_priority of 101 and each `obj` in static libs to have say... 1000, is it guaranteed that `vObjs` will get its constructor called before `obj`s in static libs? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me echo the other responses that you might want to reconsider using globals for this. However one possible (and I'm sure still flawed) improvement at least removes the need for init priority.

Instead of using a global `vector`, you create a function that returns a reference to a static local. The C++ rules make sure that the function static local is always initialized at the latest by its first use, so you don't have to worry about the vector not being initialized.

```
vector<LibInfo*>& get_gvLibInfo()
{
    vector<LibInfo*> gvLibInfo;
    return gvLibInfo;
}
```

Then your registration looks like:

```
vector<LibInfo*>& get_gvLibInfo();

void reglib()
{
    get_gvLibInfo().push_back(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going to use __attribute__((init_priority())) but this method is better it seems.

Answer (score 1):

[Global Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) have been been [considered harmful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful) for [nearly forty years](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=953353.953355) and yet people still insist on using them. Why?

Please [reconsider your design](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15) as it is brittle and is going to provide [a maintenance headache](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14) for many years to come.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880380/static-lib-loading-related-problem-please-help

                  That is why I need a global variable.

Comment: Correction, that is why *you think* you need a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU C++, they seem to guarantee the order of initialization( [click here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html) ). However I should note that if you really rely on the order of initialization then your design is fragile. Better look for alternatives when you just don't care about the order. 
HTH

Comment: Actually, the higher the value passed to `init_priority`, the lower priority it has.