# autotools and -Wl,-whole-archive

Tags: c++, autotools

Is it possible to tell autotools to link one of the libraries with -Wl,-whole-archive flag?

Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = pktanon 
pktanon_SOURCES = main.cpp
pktanon_DEPENDENCIES = $(lib_LIBRARIES)
pktanon_LDADD = libpktanon.a $(LDADD)
```

I need to link libpktanon.a with -Wl,-whole-archive flag, also I want make to execute something like this:

```
g++ -o pktanon main.o -Wl,-whole-archive libpktanon.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive -l...
```

(as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080351/linking-a-self-registering-abstract-factory))

Comment: I must admit I avoid automake but why not just write that whole thing in `pktanon_LDADD` ?

Comment: `error: linker flags such as '-Wl,-whole-archive' belong in 'pktanon_LDFLAGS'`; adding `pktanon_LDFLAGS =  -Wl,-whole-archive` generages following line and two pages of link errors:
`g++  -g -O2 -std=c++11 -Wl,-whole-archive  -o pktanon main.o -l...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175802/symbols-from-convenience-library-not-getting-exported-in-executable). You can do this:

```
pktanon_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--whole-archive,libpktanon.a,--no-whole-archive
```

The issue is that Libtool doesn't guarantee the order of linker flags on the actual command line it executes, so you have to force it like this.

Comment: To expose that libpktanon.a file as a dependency (in case it's built right alongside), you may also need a dummy `pktanon_LDADD = libpktanon.a` line.

Comment: I had similar problems before. However these flags get put at the very beginning of the command and the compilation failed.