# Add only headers of an imported module to a library in CMake

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

In CMake there are imported modules that are used to simply add external modules to local targets. For example if we want to use `boost::filesystem` library in our project we could have a `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
project(foo CXX)

find_packge(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo Boost::filesystem)
```

With above configuration CMake will add proper compiler options and include directories among required libraries to building process of the `foo`.

Now we have to build a library instead of an executable and we don't want to link `boost::filesystem` libraries to our library. We want only compiler options and include directories to be added to our target. Could we use imported modules concepts here? I mean that if we could use `Boost::filesystem` syntax for adding those options to our target?

```
project(foo CXX)

find_packge(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

add_library(foo STATIC foo.cpp)
# what should be wrote here to only add headers and configs to foo not the libs?
```

Comment: `target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `add_library(STATIC)` won't link the Boost library into itself (see e.g. [here](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=9732)).

Comment: @AmitSingh I know that but I like to use syntax like Boost::filesystem

Comment: @Florian the bug you referenced is about VC++ I think. Isn't that?

Comment: @E.Vakili Yes, but it describes the details why you won't want to link depending libraries into a static library. In short, if two static libraries would include e.g. `Boost::filesystem` and then you link both of those libraries into an executable you would get `duplicate symbol` errors. So CMake by default, does not add linker options like [`--whole-archive` for `gcc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805555/ld-linker-question-the-whole-archive-option) or `LinkLibraryDependencies` for `VC`. So `target_link_libraries(foo Boost::filesystem)` should work, it just describes the dependency.

Comment: @Florian Thanks. I got the point. Would you add and answer?

Comment: @E.Vakili You're welcome. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

`add_library(STATIC)` won't link the `target_link_libraries()` dependencies into itself.

In short, if two static libraries would include e.g. `Boost::filesystem` and then you link both of those libraries into an executable (where the external symbols get actually resolved) you would get duplicate symbol errors.

So CMake by default, does not add linker options like `--whole-archive` for `gcc` or `LinkLibraryDependencies` for `VC`.

`target_link_libraries(foo Boost::filesystem)` should work, it just describes the dependency resolved later when building a executable or shared library.

**References**

- [ld linker question: the --whole-archive option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805555/ld-linker-question-the-whole-archive-option)
- [CMake issue #9732: Cmake does not disable Link Libray Dependencies in the project settings](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=9732)