# How to make a single dynamic library, .so file from multiple static library .a files

Tags: c

I have made a DLL in Windows using the functionalities from leptonica (an imaging library) moderate them in my way as required with the attachment of other libraries (zlib, pnglib, jpeglib, jpeg2000, libtiff).

Now I want make the same in Ubuntu, here I have build all of the supporting libraries, and I am stucked at making a single dynamic library file from them as per my requirements, I have wrote a imaging.c file by invoking the functionalities and modaring the outputs as per my requirements from leptonica, and now the problem I am facing to make single dynamic library .so file from it, without any dependencies of the other ones, So that I can use it at any other application at Ubuntu, only by loading a single so file...
Also I am facing a lot of permission problem when I am trying to make  a thread safe log file from that imaging.c file . Here I am trying to dump a log which will generate from imaging.so when I will call it from any wrapped upper level application..

Answer (score 3):

You could create one big `.so` file under Linux by first compiling static versions of all the libraries that this `.so` file depends on (depending on the build process of the library, e.g. adding `--enable-static` `--disable-shared` as a parameters when running `configure` is an option).

```
gcc -shared -o bigfile.so yourobject1.o yourobject2.o -Lsomepath -lsomedependency
```

will create a `.so` file. Depending on the architecture, it is important that all code is compiled as position-independent (`-fPIC`), i.e. compile your object files as

```
gcc -fPIC -c yourobject1.c
```

This also applies to static link library dependencies (add `-fPIC` flags to makefiles, if necessary). If both a dynamic (`.so`) and a static library (`.a`) exist in the same directory, the linker will typically prefer the dynamic one. To override this, you can replace `-Lsomepath -lsomedependency` by `somepath/libsomedependency.a`.

Use

```
gcc -shared -o bigfile.so yourobject1.o yourobject2.o -Wl,--whole-archive /fullpath/libsomedependency.a
```

if some objects in `libsomedependency.a` are not referenced by `libbigfile.so` itself, but are referenced by the executable you want to finally link.

See a similar question/answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4922106/10678162

Comment: gcc -shared -o bigfile.so yourobject1.o yourobject2.o -Lsomepath -lsomedependency.      I have used same procedure, but then also when I am calling the functions from other C program by loading the so file there, then it's showing the error "unreferenced function" of the dependent static libraries.

Comment: You can double-check with `ldd bigfile.so` on the same system where you compiled `bigfile.so` whether any dependencies to dynamic libraries show up you meant to link statically.

If you know in which `.a` file the missing function is defined, you can specify the full path + name of that `.a` file directly when linking `bigfile.so` instead of using `-L` and `-l`.

You can check with `nm --defined-only libsomefile.a` all the defined symbols of archives and objects.

Comment: Is it possible to call the functions of "bigfile.so" from a C file , where I will only link the "bigfile.so", So that when I am running need not to specify the full path + name....

Comment: I mean I want to do build an so, which will be independent, which will not depends on other libraries when I am running an wrapper program over that so file, I don't want to link any other libraries except that "bigfile.so"

Comment: The full path to the libsomefile.a dependence needs to be specified when linking `bigfile.so`, not at runtime: `gcc -shared -o bigfile.so objectfiles.o /fullpath/libdependency.a`. I'm out of ideas. Maybe if you give details of what you're trying to accomplish, someone else can help you further.

Comment: Yes I have specified just like that, but then also if I am not linking them also in the run time, then it's giving error "Unreferenced definition" : but working perfectly if I run it by linking other libraries like : gcc -o test test.o bigfile.so /fullpath/libdependency.so

Comment: If `test` depends directly on objects in `libdependency.a`, you might have to make sure that these objects are linked into `libbigfile.so`, even if nothing else in `libbigfile.so` references them. This can be achieved by using the linker flag `--whole-archive`, i.e. when linking `libbigfile.so`, add `-Wl,--whole-archive` to `gcc -shared -o ...`. Edited answer correspondingly.