# Any way to tell linker to "respect" __attribute__((__used__))

Tags: c++, c, linker, static-libraries

I am trying to work around the fact that linker drops the registration in my code.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842770/700825) for details.

The problem I have with that answer is that the --whole-archive option seems like an overkill for just 1 function call. I would like to avoid huge code bloat that I assume it causes.
I found

> **attribute**((**used**))

, but that works on compile, not link level.

So I wonder if there is a specific way to tell the linker to not drop specific function call, instead of changing link options for entire program.

for clarification this is my code:

```
bool dummy = (Register(), false); // Register is never called because linker dropped entire static library
```

Comment: What do you mean by "drops the registration"?  Also, details of linker behavior are implementation-specific, so which implementation are you using?  GCC, maybe?

Comment: @JohnBollinger linked answer provides the longer explanation... in short I have bool dummy = (Register("Something1"), false); and linker drops the entire library so the Register() is never called

Comment: It's not clear that the situation you describe is analogous to the answer you reference.  It is especially not clear that the linker is responsible for the (mis)behavior involved in your case, and, moreover, the best choice of solution may well depend on context.  So please present a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 4):

> So I wonder if there is a specific way to tell the linker to not drop specific function call, instead of changing link options for entire program.

Your objective is actually to tell the linker not to drop *the definition of an unreferenced variable* (`dummy`) in whose
initialiser there is a function call that you wish to ensure is executed by your program.

`__attribute__(used)` is an attribute of functions, but not of variables, and its effect is to force the compiler to compile the function definition,
even if the function is static and appears unreferenced in the translation unit. In your case:

```
bool dummy = (Register(), false);
```

it cannot appear to the compiler that `Register` is unreferenced - it is *called* - so `__attribute__(used)` will
be redundant even if the definition of `Register()` is in the same translation unit and is static. But whether or
not the definition of `Register()` is compiled in this translation unit or some other, this *call* to `Register()`
will not be linked or executed in the program if this definition of `dummy` is not linked.

I assume you do not want to write a custom linker script, or to modify the source code so that `dummy` *is* referenced.

In that case you need to instruct the linker to *postulate* an undefined reference to `dummy`, by
passing `--undefined=dummy` in its options. This will force it to search libraries for
a definition of `dummy`, and to link archive members (and/or shared libraries) exactly as if there
actually was an undefined reference to `dummy` in the first file that is linked. No redundant code will be linked,
as is probable with `--whole-archive`.

You can pass `--undefined=<symbol>` to the linker for as many values of `<symbol>` as
you like. To pass it through `gcc/g++`, use `-Wl,--undefined=<symbol>`.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in its own section and  in the linker script:

```
KEEP(sectionname)
```

## edit

That line of code might be reduced to zeroing one register or variable