# Libtorch/Pytorch Dilemma when combined static library into one STATIC library

Tags: linker, static-libraries, pytorch, static-linking, libtorch

I have around 26 static libraries such as `liba.a, libb.a, libc.a, ..., libz.a`. There are two catches here:

1) circular dependencies between for example `liba.a` and `libb.a`;

2) some `lib*.a` has static global registration code which is unreferenced, but shall NOT be stripped away.

Thanks to stackoverflow, I managed to solve above two problems with the ld option  `-Wl,--whole-archive  -la -lb -lc -ld -le ...(omitted)... -lz -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lpthread -lm -ldl -lrt -fopenmp` , **and the executable binary works!** It is also explained in [ld linker question: the --whole-archive option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805555/ld-linker-question-the-whole-archive-option)

Now I need to combine all 26 `lib*.a` into one static library `liball.a`. Also thanks to stackoverflow, the below MRI script.mri successuflly produces `liball.a` through the command `ar -M < script.mri`

```
create liball.a
addlib liba.a
addlib libb.a
addlib libc.a
addlib libd.a
... //omitted
addlib libz.a
save
end
```

However, here comes the issue when linking with newly combined static library `liball.a`:

1) with the option `-Wl,--whole-archive  -lall  -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lpthread -lm -ldl -lrt -fopenmp` FAILS!! It generates thousands of `multiple defined symbols error` or `undefined symbols error`!!

2) without the option `-Wl,--whole-archive`, the link command with`-lall -lpthread -lm -ldl -lrt -fopenmp` successfully produced the executable binary. However, **the binary fails to execute** , complaining some Device Registration code error. I understand that this is caused by **some CPU initialization code getting pruned away** when linking. Below is the detailed error

```
 p INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at ../c10/core/impl/DeviceGuardImplInterface.h:132, please report a bug to PyTorch. DeviceGuardImpl for cpu is not available (getDeviceGuardImpl at ../c10/core/impl/DeviceGuardImplInterface.h:132)
```

This isssue is also mentioned here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14367

One way to solve it is to use selective registration. Could anyone share more details on this?

**This question is NOT a duplicate of [How to merge two "ar" static libraries into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one)
The MRI script method is from highest vote answer of the above link, and it is not working. 
Please remove the duplicate mark so that people can contribute. Thanks.**

Comment: What does *"complaining some Device Registration code error..."* mean?

Comment: @jww thank you for asking. Please refer to updated post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two "ar" static libraries into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one)

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for your comment. However, I do not think it is a duplicate. The method mentioned in the link you provided is used here, but does not work.

Comment: So you tried it? You unpacked all the libraries into `.o` files and regenerated the ar library? You get `duplicated symbols` as expected, hm. Maybe unpack all libraries to `.o` files, and then re-compile with gcc?

Comment: Those lib*.a have duplicate symbols, thus cannot use the -x way to do it. ar command MRI script is the native way to do it.

Comment: @KamilCuk Could you please remove the duplicate mark. The MRI script used here is from the highest vote answer in the link you provided. Thanks.