# Can a shared object library access objects from a statically linked library?

Tags: g++, shared-libraries

I have an application which contains a statically linked library (`libUtils.a`).

I turned a library which i previously had linked statically into a shared object library.
This library (`SheepPopWapper.so`) also needs access to some of the functions in `libUtils.a`.

When i run my application i get a runtime error:

```
[DynPopFactory::collectPlugins] Couldn't open so [/home/jody/progs/QHG4/dynpops/so_dir/SheepPopWrapper.so]: /home/jody/progs/QHG4/dynpops/so_dir/SheepPopWrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10MessLogger17s_sCurHeaderErrorB5cxx11E
```

The Object `MessLogger` is in libUtils.a and is visible in the application:

```
 $ nm  MainAppDyn | grep MessLogger17s
000000000026d7e0 B _ZN10MessLogger17s_sCurHeaderErrorB5cxx11E
```

However, if i link `libUtils.a` to `SheepPopWrapper.so`,  everything works as expected.

But somehow it bothers me that during run time there are two copies of `libUtils`. This situation also caused an actual problem because `libUtils` contains an object i implemented as a singleton, and in this situation there are two singletons (one for each copy of `libUtils`).

So the question is: can a shared object library access objects from a statically linked object?

And if this is the case, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is: can a shared object library access objects from a statically linked object?

Yes, but the symbol must be *exported* from the main binary (must be present in its *dynamic* symbol table).

You can verify that the symbol is currently *not* present using:

```
nm -D MainAppDyn | grep _ZN10MessLogger17s_sCurHeaderErrorB5cxx11E
```

which should produce no output.

Once you've confirmed that this is the case, you can relink `MainAppDyn` with `-Wl,--export-dynamic` flag, and confirm that the symbol becomes exported repeating the same `nm -D ...` command above.

This may not be the best approach though, as it makes the binary slightly bigger and dynamic linking slightly slower by exporting *all* symbols in the dynamic symbol table.

If you have a reasonably recent linker, using `-Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol=_ZN10MessLogger17s_sCurHeaderErrorB5cxx11E` may be better (this only forces this one symbol to be exported).

On the other hand, you may discover that `SheepPopWrapper.so` requires a lot more symbols from `libUtils.a`, in which case exporting them all could be a reasonable approach after all.

**Update:**

> i got a new runtime error symbol lookup error: `/home/jody/progs/QHG4/dynpops/so_dir//GrassPopWrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12LBControllerC1Ev`
> The LBController is part of libUtils (as seen by nm) but it does not show up in an nm call for the application. Is this a consequence of smart linking?

This is a consequence of "normal" linking -- the linker doesn't pull objects into the binary unless it can see that that this symbol is being used. See [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) blog post to understand how the linker decides.

You can work around this by:

1. Adding `-Wl,--whole-archive -lUtils -Wl,--no-whole-archive` or
2. Adding `-Wl,-u,_ZN12LBControllerC1Ev` to the link line of `MainAppDyn` (repeat for each symbol that you want to force-include into the main application).

For option 1, see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842770/50617).

Comment: The nm command before using the --exoort-dynamic  produced no output. Afterwards it did, but i got a new runtime error ``symbol lookup error: /home/jody/progs/QHG4/dynpops/so_dir//GrassPopWrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12LBControllerC1Ev``. GrassPopWrapper is a second dynamic object used in the application whic also uses objects from libUtils. The LBController is part  of libUtils (as seen by nm) but it does not show up in an nm call for the application. Is this a consequence of smart linking? (i.e. the linker saw no use if LBContoller inside the application and therefore threw it out?)

Comment: @Russian: Thank you for your suggestions. I had to use the ``--export-dynamic`` option in addition to the ``--whole-archive`` and ``no-whole-archive`` options to get my application working, but now my problem is solved.