# Linking ".a" files, apply --whole-archive to a single .o file of the .a file only?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I have a single .o file of an `.a` file that I want to force to be linked and not considered unused, but I don't want to take the whole static library.

Is there an option to tell the linker to consider that .o file used, without referencing a dummy variable from that .o file? Like the following imaginary syntax?

```
gcc --use-o-file=archive.a:file.o  archive.a main.cc
```

---

The motivation is a `..._qmltyperegistrations.cpp` file of Qt, where Qt registers a couple of classes for use with QML/Javascript, and whose code is intended to execute at the start of the program. Unfortunately, this file is discarded by the linker, because no symbol of the file is referenced by anyone.

The CMake-functions of Qt do not apparently take care of this themselves, so I try to find a workaround. If these files were to be put into a CMake "OBJECT"-library, instead of being added to a "STATIC" library, this should have worked.

---

Answering followup questions - all are "Yes", but I would rather not put references to the .cc file in my code. I would like to keep all the logic behind CMake functions.

- Are you in charge of building the static library?

Yes!

- Can you tinker with how it is built? Can you create a relocatable object file?

Yes! Would this fix the problem?

- Or can you add an object file that contains (a) references to at least one relevant symbol from each of the object files you must have linked and (b) a symbol (function) that your code does reference, even if it doesn't actually get called?

Yes!

---

My current workaround is to do the following

```
execute_process(
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "void qml_register_types_ZesFrontend() { }"
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -xc++ -S -w -o - -
   COMMAND grep -Po [[^_Z.+(?=:)]]
   OUTPUT_VARIABLE mangled_initializer
)

target_link_options(zes_frontend INTERFACE SHELL:-u "${mangled_initializer}")
```

This first generates the mangled name of the initialization-function that is defined in the `.o` file in question. It then tells the compiler whenever it links the `.a` file, that it should consider its mangled name as yet undefined, so that it links the `.o`

Since this is a bit hacky and not very portable, I will instead generate a temporary output file with cmake, and reference the symbol there.

Comment: Extract the object file from the library and link it explicitly on the command line?  Can you provide motivation for this?  What's in the object file that you want?  I could imagine that it is library version information, for example.

Comment: "but I don't want to take the whole static library" - when linking a static library (basically just a collection of object files) the linker will only include the bits you actually use, it won't include "the whole static library".

Comment: @Jesper if I use `--whole-archive`, in order to force inclusion of the single .o file even if it is unused, it will take the entire library.

Comment: Why do you want to use `--whole-archive` in the first place? Why not just let the linker pick the bits you actually *use*? Why would you want to include stuff that your application does not use?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I extended the question with a motivation.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I included motivation in my question.

Comment: Can you use a shared object (DLL) instead of an archive library?

Comment: How does that file "executes at the start of the program" if the linker thinks it is unused?

Comment: yes, in the past when I've had this issue, have created an OBJECT library and then linked that into the static library (and, unfortunately into the final binaries that reference it -- if you don't do this then unused functions get discarded)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that would be an option but I would like to keep using a. ".a" file. I guess currently there is no nice solution.. I will answer once there's a workaround that works.

Comment: @Botje i'm sorry I meant that the code is intended to be executed. Fixed.

Comment: Are you in charge of building the static library?  Can you tinker with how it is built?  Can you create a relocatable object file?  Or can you add an object file that contains (a) references to at least one relevant symbol from each of the object files you must have linked and (b) a symbol (function) that your code does reference, even if it doesn't actually get called?

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mre] that shows a comparable situation. Shouldn't you fix the "the linker does not agree that this code is ever referenced" problem first?

Comment: Also ... are you certain the problem isn't simply the order of linker arguments? `archive.a` should come *after* the files that need it (ie `main.cc`) as that is how linkers work

Comment: I am sure/certain of all of the above, unfortunately. My current workaround is given above.

Comment: @TooTone I have posted my workaround using `-u`.

Comment: I still fail to understand how code from a static library could be used at runtime but the linker fails to detect that. That's really odd.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the file is not used at runtime but it is intended to be used.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb  "the file is not used at runtime but it is intended to be used" - then don't worry about it as long as it isn't used, and once it *is* used then the linker will surely include the bits you need.  I still fail to see the problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl check https://stackoverflow.com/a/842770/34509

Comment: That link doesn't really provide a good argument for using `--whole-archive` when linking an *executable*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl both the linked answer and in my question, a static library is linked into an executable. Now it's me who doesn't understand :D

Answer (score 0):

My final workaround looks like this:

```
qt_add_qml_module(zes_frontend
   URI ZesFrontend
   ...
)

file(CONFIGURE 
   OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zes_frontend_qmltyperegistrationsuser.cpp 
   CONTENT "
      void qml_register_types_ZesFrontend();
      static volatile auto use = &qml_register_types_ZesFrontend;
   "
   @ONLY)
target_sources(zes_frontend INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zes_frontend_qmltyperegistrationsuser.cpp)
```

The `file(CONFIGURE` syntax is used so that we have access to CMake-Variables (the name of the module, for example). For purpose of simplicity, we hard-code it here.